# MUnit - Mock JMS, DB and HTTP connectors in domain

Tags: database, http, mocking, jms, munit

I have mule services which relies on mule domain for all the connectors (http, db, jms).

The problem I am facing is when I write MUnit for a particular service/flow, I am unable to mock the connectors in the DOMAIN project. For example, domain has a JMS connector (reconnect forever), it keeps trying to connect. All this happens before the munit actually gets invoked. How can I make all the connectors not connect anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You have only JMS connector configuration(i.e **jms:connector**) in your domain project i guess, that you no need to mock. Inbound/outbound JMS connectors are there in your actual flow/service only. Just you need to mock the inbound/outbound JMS connectors in your actual flow.

sample code:

`<mock:when messageProcessor="jms:outbound-endpoint" doc:name="jms-mock">
   <mock:with-attributes>
     <mock:with-attribute name="doc:name" whereValue="#[matchContains('your jms doc:name')]"/>
     </mock:with-attributes>
   <mock:then-return payload="#[]"/>
 </mock:when>`

You can add some more attributes of your connector to the above code.